# Assign activity: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: object, variables, reference, instance, uipath

I have already **assigned data to a String** and I'm still getting the same error.

Would you kindly explain what could be the possible reason for this?

Error in UiPath:

[image: error]

Comment: Sorry this is too less info. Could you upload your process somewhere? Also show us what you have as Variables and if it has some default value. Also how did you create the variable?